# Vagrant will not boot with Parallals - Host OS Administrator Error

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, parallels, puphpet

### Summary:

I am attempting to get Vagrant up and running while using [Parallels as a Virtual Machine](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels) provider.

### What I've done:

1. I downloaded and installed [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads) (the OS X version).
2. I uploaded the following `config.yaml` file to [puphpet.com](https://puphpet.com/) that has been set up for development our website. (See below).
3. I ran `vagrant up` and it spent several minutes working and logging status to the terminal.
4. It stopped with the error:

> There was an error while command execution. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["prlctl", "clone", "packer-parallels-iso", "--name", "packer-parallels-iso_1420581521788_27867"]
>
> Stderr: 
> Failed to clone the VM: The operation failed. To perform this operation, you must enter the host OS administrator's credentials.

Here is the config.yaml that I used (where `ourwebsite` is the site we are working on):

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_url: puphpet/centos65-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '512'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: parallels
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.58.101
            forwarded_port:
                yE0yzJcPFTlS:
                    host: '9233'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            yzkPrGht93ro:
                owner: ''
                group: ''
                source: ../
                target: /var/www/sites/www.ourwebsite.com/
                sync_type: nfs
                rsync:
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - ImageMagick
        - vim-common
        - php-soap
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        ch8onl5p0ias:
            servername: ourwebsite.mag
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/sites/www.ourwebsite.com/base/
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            directories:
                wpd0snz5xtxt:
                    provider: directory
                    path: /var/www/sites/www.ourwebsite.com/base/
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - all
                        - granted
                    custom_fragment: ''
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        89celicdwbdc:
            proxy: ''
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome.dev
            listen_port: '80'
            location: .php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
            - imagick
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: '0'
        port: '0'
    ini: {  }
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: ''
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: ''
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: root
    adminer: 0
    databases:
        GSs7e7BZdo0r:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: ourwebsite
            host: localhost
            user: our_site
            password: thepassword
            sql_file: ../databases/output.sql
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: ''
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: ''
        port: ''
```

### Aftermath:

I have done quite a bit of searching, but this doesn't seem to be a very common problem. The [issue came up](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/issues/67), but was supposed to be resolved with Parallels 10 (which I have confirmed that I have) and Vagrant 1.7.1 (which I have confirmed I have). I also made sure all of the settings were un-checked.

I have tried:

- Un/re-installing Vagrant
- Un/re-installing Parallels 10
- `sudo vagrant up` and the like
- Rebooting
- Lots of digging.

Any time I run `vagrant up` with circumstances similar to what I've described, it almost immediately gives an that exact error message after these two lines:

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'parallels' provider...
> ==> default: Importing base box 'puphpet/centos65-x64'...

I have been unable to figure out a way to dig more into the problem.

### Questions:

Based off of the details that I've given, is the problem with my Vagrant configuration files, or is it with Parallels? Is there a way to get a more human-readable error message of what could be causing it? Obviously, I'm more then happy to provide the "host OS administrator's credentials", but am anaware of how I may do so.

-- as a side note, I am new to Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

[This github issue comment](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/issues/67#issuecomment-32774326) may have the solution - Under Parallels Desktop -> Settings -> Advanced you may have some boxes ticked that should be, "Require Password to:" section.

As a side note, this seems to be an issue with the vagrant-parallels plugin and you may have a better chance of receiving a response from them, since they're a commercial entity.

Comment: Thank you - I should contact them. As a side note, the "Require Password to:", at least according to a comment further down, *shouldn't* affect Vagrant in Parallels 10 (which I have). Either way, I will be giving that a try as well.